# stop bypass of login page

Tags: php, authentication

I have this as my login page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--PHP login System by WEBDEVTRICK (https://webdevtrick.com) -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login | Webdevtrick.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
require('config.php');
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'
and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: inventory.php");
         }else{
    echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
<br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
    }else{
?>
    <form class="login" action="" method="post" name="login">
    <h1 class="login-title">Login | Webdevtrick.com</h1>
    <input type="text" class="login-input" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="login-input" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="login-button">
  <p class="login-lost">New Here? <a href="registration.php">Register</a></p>
  </form>

<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this as my auth.php script which I include on my pages:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>
```

Right now I can just go to the inventory.php whether I am logged in or not.
How can I make sure that I can only do this when logged in?

Comment: `session_start();` should go to the most top of the script

Comment: You should probably implement a way to log out. That way you can test it.

Comment: What does your `inventory.php` looks like? Are you sure you've included `auth.php`?

Comment: `and password='".md5($password)."'"` ... ouch, find a newer, less broken tutorial (using [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php))!

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you shouldn't use only `session.start()` because is not secure too.

Instead you should use [Prepared Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Simply, a **prepared statement** is a way of preparing the MySQL call, without storing the variables.

**Safe PHP Login Example**

```
<?php
include 'session.php'; // Secure Session Script
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
   include 'database.php';

   $username=$_POST['username']; 
   $password=$_POST['password'];

   $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username = ?";

   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
   $stmt->bind_param("s",$username); // As much "s" as variables to bind are
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
   if ($result && password_verify($password, $result['password']))
   {
      $_SESSION['login']= $username;
      header('Location: Success.php');
   } else {
      header('Location: index.php');
      $_SESSION['error'] = 'Invalid Credentials';
      exit();
   }
} else {
   header('Location: index.php');
   exit();
}
?>
```

**Secure Session**

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Prevents the session ID from appearing in a referer header
session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','localhost',false,true); // Determines the duration of cookies
session_start(); // Start Session
session_regenerate_id(); // Regenerate Session ID 
?>
```

And eventually... **Success.php**

```
<?php
include '../functions/s-session.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { // if login is not set then...
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit();
}
?>
// html page
```